# Sorting object of lat longs from top left to bottom right

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
Object {
  "-M2p5oNuWAJFhZKv64ht": Object {
    "latitude": -37.8263853,
    "longitude": 144.9951198
  },
  "-M39Q4SBJbGZjUQHfvGa": Object {
    "latitude": -37.805684,
    "longitude": 144.893994
  },
  "-M39Q4pAz5sF0tF4d3XK": Object {
    "latitude": -37.8086484,
    "longitude": 144.8823838
  },
  "-M39Q4zL7ZNzqdHaJLvZ": Object {
    "latitude": -37.8076142,
    "longitude": 144.8838452
  },
  "-M39Q58FwvBP2HoDZGD9": Object {
    "latitude": -37.808319,
    "longitude": 144.892747
  },
  "-M39Q5Idu-EgkAn0Vd2Q": Object {
    "latitude": -37.8108465,
    "longitude": 144.8798158
  },
  "-M39Q5U8XCq1h4ieo_Db": Object {
    "latitude": -37.802019,
    "longitude": 144.8909805
  }
  ...
}
```

Imagining that these coordinates relate to the red pins on the below map, I would like to start from the upper most left corner from each pin and sort them as if a square was slowly expanding from that point. I can only think of getting the starting lat long and incrementing +1 to those, then checking if a value is < either variable, repeat. I imagine this is obviously incredibly inefficient and would love a more robust and expandable way.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to sort your array by the max value of your 2 coordinates.

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => {
    const aMax = Math.max(a.latitude, a.longitude);
    const bMax = Math.max(b.latitude, b.longitude);

    if (aMax < bMax) return -1;
    if (bMax < aMax) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: You're awesome. Question. Would just adding lat and long together (given they are positive) work? Then just sort by lowest to highest?

Comment: Thanks! Adding them together wouldn't work, that'd be a different kind of sort. Try to think of examples to test, like with adding, a point at (10, 10) would come before one at (15, 0)